# How can webview keep loading if it was destroyed?

Tags: android, webview, android-lifecycle, android-intentservice, android-ondestroy

I created a `WebVew` inside an `IntentService` onCreate() and tracked (using `Log.i`) it's lifecycle until `IntentService`'s onDestroy().

I realized that `WebView` keeps loading after `IntentService` be destroyed.

Can anyone explain me what happens here?

Details: I concluded it because I made some redirect logic inside `WebView` onPageFinished(), and also tracked loads.